# Replace 0's with FALSE and 1's with TRUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, boolean-expression

I'm using a `COUNTIF` formula to find matches between two ranges.  Of course, `COUNTIF` returns a numerical value, but I need TRUE or FALSE values.  So I added `NOT()` to the formula, which gave me TRUE/FALSE, but in my case, the results were backward, so I added an additional `NOT()` to reverse the results and this works fine for my purposes.

My question is: is there a better way to do this?  Obviously, this isn't a lot of characters to type (I've put more effort into typing this question...), but if there is a simpler, cleaner solution, I'd like to know.

Here is my full formula:

```excel
=NOT(NOT(COUNTIF(projectSelections!B2:B&projectSelections!C2:C,itemsAssociations!A3:A&itemsAssociations!B3:B)))
```

Comment: Without seeing your data, I'd disagree that your formula does "find matches between two ranges".

Comment: You're right! As it turns out, I'm having to edit what I've done.  But I still wanted to know if there was an alternative to the double negation that I had done.  But actually, the goal is to see if there are NOT matches.

Comment: Leaving aside the worthwhileness of the formula, you could, of course simply use IF, such as `=if(COUNTIF(B2:B&C2:C,F2:F&G2:G)=0,"FALSE","TRUE")`

Comment: @Tedinoz you need to remove the quotes to return the real booleans

Comment: @Tedinoz, yes, I considered that, but was seeking something simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know specifically about google sheets, but in general a double negation is not an unusual technique to convert a numeric value to a boolean.

Alternatively, there is also the possibility to check if the value is not equal to zero, which in the case of google sheets can apparently be done with the [`NE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093981?hl=en) function:  `NE(COUNTIF(...) ,0)`. As explained in the documentation, `NE(a,b)` is equivalent to `a <> b`.

Comment: That's great!  Yeah, I don't know that it saves me any time or characters, but just learning a new function and having that on my toolbelt is really what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A10=B1:B10)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A1:A10, "^"&B1:B10&"$"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A10=B1:B10, TRUE))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(NE(A1:A10, B1:B10))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(""&A1:A10, "^"&B1:B10&"$"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking. To get TRUE and FALSE just use

```
=COUNTIF(...)=0
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! Although, to get my true result, it would be `=COUNTIF(...)<>0`, but that's definitely the easiest solution!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with what you did.  Another option is to use Perl  or Python to clean up the data file.  You could export in CSV format or clean up before going into google docs.